# Find the degree of the differential equation of the family of circles touching the lines $y^2-x^2=0$ and lying in the first and second quad

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The centre obvious lies on the $y$ axis

So
$$x^2 + (y-y_1)^2 = r^2$$

Where $r^2 = \frac{y_1^2}{2}$

Then
$$x^2 + y^2+y_1^2 -2yy_1 = \frac{y_1^2}{2}$$

Since the degree of the equation is determined by the number of constants, the degree here should be 2, because $y_1$ and $y_1^2$ are separate constants

Or maybe they are not. Both constants are dependent on the value of $y_1$, so I am confused whether to have the degree 1 or 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This family of circle is given by ONE parameter family of circles
$$x^2+(y-k)^2=k^2/2~~~~(1)$$
We need to get a FIRST order ODE only.
D. (1) w.r.t. $x$, to get
$$2x+2(y-k)y'=0 \implies k-y=\frac{x}{y'} \implies k=(x/y'+y)$$
Putting these in (1) we get
$$x^2+(x/y')^2=\frac{1}{2}(x/y'+y)^2,$$
which may be simplified further.